# Store special symbols in YAML

Tags: yaml

I need store special symbols like ® and ™ in my YAML, because some part of system use this for creating headers in emails.

For example:

```
email:
  app:
    test_subject: "Some test message with the special symbol®"
```

When i test my mail api, in my mails i have some troubles with special symbol, for example:

```
Hi, this is Some test message with the special symbolÂ®
                                                     ^
                                                     |
                       _______________________________
```

How i can fix it and store those characters in my yaml file?

Comment: Look at the raw email headers. Is the subject line correctly UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: @Gereon i decode it. b'Some test message with the special symbol\xc2\xae'
\xc2\xae it ® as I see.

Comment: That seems wrong. You should see something similar to `=utf-8?Q?Hi, this is Some test...` Check RFC 1342 for more info.